# only dictionaries are available in given json api . how to retrive all data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
{  

 "1": 
{  
   "Name": "Afghanistan",     "Rate": 0.435,     "PhoneNo": "93"   },   
"2": 

{  
   "Name": "Afghanistan",     "Rate": 0.6225,     "PhoneNo": "9370, 9372, 9375, 9376, 9377, 9378, 9379"   }, 

"3": 
{     "Name": "Albania",     "Rate": 0.2775,     "PhoneNo": "35543, 355422, 355423, 355424"   }, 

  "4": {     "Name": "Albania",     "Rate": 0.3825,     "PhoneNo": "3553, 3555, 3558, 35521, 35522, 35524, 35526, 35527, 35528, 35529, 35546, 35547, 35548, 35549, 35572"   },  

 "5": {     "Name": "Albania",     "Rate": 0.7125,     "PhoneNo": "35566, 35567, 35568, 35569"   },   

"6": {     "Name": "Albania",     "Rate": 2.5575,     "PhoneNo": "3554249"   },....
.
.
.


"50:
{........ } ..
```

so , this is my api data .. 
how can i get all data from this link using json ?? 
which method should i use ? ......

here is my code , look into it and guide me further

```
NSURLRequest *Request=[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"]];                           
NSError *error;                           
NSURLResponse *response;      
NSData *data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:Request returningResponse:&response error:&error];                            

if (data != nil)  
{                               
     NSString *content=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];                                

     if (content.length != 0) {                                                           
         NSDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];                                                                        
         NSDictionary *dict1=[dict objectForKey:@"1"];                                                                                                                                                       
         NSString *str1=[dict1 objectForKey:@"Name"];                                                                                
         NSLog(@"%@",str1);                                                                         
         NSNumber *rate=[dict1 objectForKey:@"Rate"];                                                                        
         NSString *str2=[dict1 objectForKey:@"PhoneNo"];                                                                                
     }                                                                    
}
```

Comment: dict must be having all data?

Comment: what data are you expecting to retrieve? Which data do you want from the json?

Comment: i want name,rate and phone num ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `allKeys` of `NSDictionary` you get the array of keys, then sort it and then get data from `NSDictionary` like this way.

```
NSDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];                                                                        
NSComparisonResult (^sortBlock)(id,id) = ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
};
NSArray *keyArray = [[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:sortBlock];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < [keyArray count]; i++) {
    NSString *key = [keyArray objectAtIndex:i];
    [array addObject:[dict objectForKey:key]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a model class Country, then store each country object as bellow code,

```
NSInteger count = [[dict allKeys] count];
NSMutableArray *countries = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     Country *country = [[Country alloc] init];

     NSDictionary *dict1=[dict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];                                                                                                                                                       
     country.name = [dict1 objectForKey:@"Name"]; 
     country.rate = [dict1 objectForKey:@"Rate"];
     country.phoneNo = [dict1 objectForKey:@"PhoneNo"];

     [countries addObject:country];
}
```